# redirectToUrl() not working after compiling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can't figure this out. While testing in flash (cs 6) redirect works, after compiling, and running from browser or with with flash player - NOT.

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

link.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotourl);

function gotourl(event:MouseEvent):void{
    // ...
    var url:String = "http://google.com";
    var urlrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    navigateToURL(urlrequest);
}
```

updated

just checked on another machine - works fine, guess its my flash player .. or something

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to navigateToURL:

```
navigateToURL(urlrequest, "_blank");
```

This is often the case of the problem, because sometimes browsers don't allow you to change url of browser directly from Flash. You could also try to add `allowScriptAccess="always"` to your embed tag in html. The other way around is to use the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class, if you have access to javascript on the page. Note that you must add `allowScriptAccess="always"` tag to use that class.

Comment: no, i tried setting second parameter to function and setting always for allowscriptaccess.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to add your swf location to trusted locations list at http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html